# Scala Parser Combinator ignoring errors in optional elements

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

We are building a parser for a DSL that looks like SQL. Like in SQL it has multiple blocks namely select, where, order by, group by etc. We made some parts of the query like where, order by etc. optional. When we do this the parser ignores all input errors.

DSL Code Snippet

```
case class Query(select: Select, where: Where)
case class Select(cols: Seq[String])
case class Where(conditions: Seq[String])

object QueryLanguage extends StandardTokenParsers {  
    lazy val sql: Parser[Query] = select_block ~ (where_block?) ^^ {case slct ~ whr => Query(slct, whr.getOrElse(null))}
    lazy val select_block:  Parser[Select] = "SELECT" ~> rep1sep(ident, ",") ^^ { case cols => Select(cols) }
    lazy val where_block: Parser[Where] = "WHERE" ~> rep1sep(ident, "and") ^^ { case conds => Where(conds) }
}
```

Any syntax errors in the select block are reported but not on other blocks. This is frustrating to someone who wants to have a where block in their query but they have no way to report errors in their definition.

For example, a SQL like shown below simply ignores the WHERE clause without reporting error (note and keyword is misspelled)

```
select A, B
WHERE a=1 andd b=2
```

The SQL parses correctly if I were to fix the spelling in the input or make the where caluse mandatory in the DSL like shown below

```
lazy val sql: Parser[Query] = select ~ where ~ (orderby?)
```

Is there another way to handle this or override this default behavior?